# jQuery UI Not being loaded properly? Dialog method not found

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an issue with my jQuery UI dialog on this page (and this page only):

http://www.satelliteinternet.com/

I'm not sure what the issue is as it's working on all the other pages on the site. The error I'm getting is the $("#DealerSearch") object has no dialog method. Very odd indeed.

Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They only difference i see here is that jquery is loaded twice on your homepage and once on the other pages. Try removing the one loaded from google

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: On the home page `jquery` loaded twice, one inside `head` and one inside `footer div`.

Comment: This was it, thank you! Sometimes it just takes a fresh set of eyes I guess. There were duplicate references to jQuery on the other pages too, but I took those off yesterday.